# Restricting a Users access to run jobs to a certain time

Tags: hadoop

How do I restrict a specfic user from accessing the cluster at certain times.

For example I only want user "Bob" to be able to access the cluster between the times 3:00am and 4:00am

Any help would be greatly appreciated.